# Return True if a string doesn't match regex javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to write a function to determine if an input is "shouting". Which hear means writing in all caps. The logic I'm using for that is

```
if (this.toUpperCase() === this)
```

Which is working just fine, however, the problem I've having is that strictly numerical or symobolic (?, ! etc.) strings are being flagged as shouting.

I've tried something to the effect of

```
if (this.toUpperCase() === this && !this.match(/a-zA-Z/))
```

However, that doesn't seem to do the trick. Does the mistake lie in my javascript or my regex? Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: why not `!this.match(/[a-z]/) && this.match(/[A-Z]/)`?

Comment: do you want to check that all letters are uppercase or that it _only_ has letters and that they're uppercase?

Comment: Because there are quite a few more letters than `A-Z`

Comment: You seem to be missing the grouping, it's `[a-zA-Z]`

Comment: @zzzzBov - that doesn't check if the entire string is uppercase, just if it contains one uppercase character ?

Comment: Should be `if ( str.match(/[a-zA-Z]/) && str.toUpperCase() === str ) {`

Comment: @adeneo, it checks that there are no lowercase characters (ignoring i18n) and that it contains some capitals. `A205` will be considered shouting, but so will `HOW ARE YOU?` Can't disambiguate without more details.

Comment: @Tomalak has a good point about i18n, but shouting is likely handled differently between cultures and *that* problem is too broad for this SO question.

Comment: @zzzzBov - indeed it does, didn't notice the negated first match

Comment: @adeneo, I should have used `this.match(/[^a-z]/)` instead to make the intent clearer.

Comment: THIS EEEZN'T SHOUtIN'?

Comment: How would you expect to handle "OMG", "CIA" or any other acronym?

Comment: re-reading the question it's not really clear what a "right" answer would be... the question is about achieving a goal that's doesn't have to match the process in the title. But then the final question is where the mistake in the second line of code is. There's lots of things "wrong" with that second line of code, but a lot of what's wrong has to do with what "shouting" means in context...

Answer (score 3):

Your second condition is wrong: you're checking for a string that doesnt contain letters (upper or lowercase). And you forgot the square brackets in the regex.
You should check for a string containing at least one uppercase letter:

```
if ((this.toUpperCase() === this) && (this.match(/[A-Z]/)))
```

Comment: Uhm, wouldn't the `/i` make the match case-insensitive, and it would match anything

Comment: Sorry, forget about the "i" (it works in any case since first condition checks if everything is uppercase)

Comment: Please elaborate how this code answers the question.

Comment: @JAL He asked for working JS code to check if a string is uppercase, without returning true on non-letters strings. And i answered with working JS code, there's not much to explain

Comment: @JAL Btw, edited my answer to explain where the error was and how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
var str = this;
var R = function(regex) {
    return (str.match(regex) || []).length
};
var ratio = {
    upper: R(/[A-Z]/g),
    lower: R(/[a-z]/g),
    letters: R(/[A-Z]/gi),
    spaces: R(/\s/g),
    non_letters: R(/[^A-Z]/gi)
};
```

and then you can use some logic like:

```
// if only upper case letters
if (this.length == ratio.upper + ratio.spaces)
    // do something ..
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is a good answer for dealing with a more realistic meaning of shouting, and using regex to do it. Obviously "shouting" is still problematic, but the ratios isn't a terrible approach

Comment: `lower: R(/[A-Z]/g),` should be `lower: R(/[a-z]/g),` methinks

Answer (score 0):

I think [Fabius' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35802632/211627) is what you are looking for, but I'd recommend a few changes to the logic as you may end up catching more than and not all that you want:

- THIS IS SHOUTING!!
- Y?
- is the above SHOUTING?
- Please use SSCCE.
- wHAT ABOUT THIS? IS THIS SHOUTING?

Here's what I'd recommend:

```js
var resultsDiv = $('#results'),
    tests = [
      { string: 'THIS IS SHOUTING!!' },
      { string: 'Y?' },
      { string: 'is the above SHOUTING?' },
      { string: 'Please use SSCCE.' },
      { string: 'wHAT ABOUT THIS? IS THIS SHOUTING?' }
    ];

$.each( tests, function(i, test){
  var string = test.string,
      isShouting;
  
  // First, strip out non-alpha characters:
  string = string.replace(/[^a-z]/ig, '');
  
  var beforeLength = string.length;
  
  // Now remove all uppercase characters:
  string = string.replace(/[^A-Z]/g, '');
  
  var afterLength = string.length;
  
  // Now, compare the length of the before and after, with a threshold for short string.
  // Basically, if the before string is at least 4 characters long and more than half of
  // the string is uppercase, then flag it as "shouting".
  isShouting =
    ( beforeLength >= 4 && ( afterLength / beforeLength >= 0.50 ) );
  
  $('<div>')
    .text(test.string)
    .css('color', 'darkblue')
    .appendTo( resultsDiv );
  
  $('<div>')
    .text(isShouting ? "SHOUTING DETECTED!" : "quiet and controlled.")
    .css('margin-bottom', '15px')
    .css('color', isShouting ? 'red' : 'black')
    .appendTo( resultsDiv );
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="results">
</div>
```

You can fiddle around with the thresholds to find something that will match your expectations. 50% uppercase may be too strict. Just keep in mind that there will always be exceptions to any rule, so make sure that the consequences of "shouting" aren't too onerous.

Also note that I haven't done much to internationalize this example. I leave that as an exercise to the reader. The example above is enough to demonstrate the theory.

Answer (score -2):

You're asking about the regex, but your initial example doesn't use it so it sounds like you're going to regex just to cover the mistakes in the first example.

You don't need regex to do what you're looking to do.

If the string is okay to hold non-letter characters but the letters need to be all uppercase, try

```
if (this.toLowerCase() !== this)
```

to support internationalization you might want

```
if (this.toLocaleLowerCase() !== this)
```

Some languages have different casing rules, as explained in the docs [toLacleLowerCase() doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLocaleLowerCase)